# Suppose the twelve vectors start from 6:00 at the bottom instead of (0, 0) at the center.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose the twelve vectors start from 6:00 at the bottom instead of (0, 0) at the center.The vector to 12:00 is doubled to (0, 2).The new twelve vectors add to?

Solution: Moving the origin to 6:00 adds j = (0, 1) to every vector. So the sum of twelve vectors
changes from 0 to 12j = (0, 12).

I don't understand this solution.

Comment: Can you add what exactly you did not understand about the solution?

Comment: Did you solve for the case when all vectors began at origin?

Comment: Take the 3:00 vector as an example. From $\vec{x}=(1,0)$ it becomes $\vec{x}+\vec{j}=(1,1)$. Since this is the case for each vector, $\sum_i\vec{x}_i=0$ becomes $\sum_i(\vec{x}_i+\vec{j})=\cdots$.

Comment: @Chrystomath Thank you so much!